# multiple popup form in a page some buttons connected using js i need a way for showing errors

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

**VIEW::::**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="cont">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="outerbox">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('Login/client_login'); ?>">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="box2" required="true" placeholder="Email"></input>
          </br>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="box3" required="true" minlength="6" placeholder="Password"></input>
          <br/>
          <button name="login_button" id="login_button">Login</button>
        </form>
        <button name="reg_button" id="reg_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Signup</button>
        <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<!--vendor signin-->

<div id="ven_myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="ven_cont">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <?php $error="";?>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="ven_outerbox">
        <?php echo form_open(base_url('Login/vendor'));?>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="ven_box2" required="true" placeholder="Email"></input>
          </br>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="ven_box3" required="true" minlength="6" placeholder="Password">
          <button type="submit" name="ven_login_button" id="ven_login_button">Login</button>
          <?php echo form_close();?>
            <button name="ven_reg_button" id="ven_reg_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ven_myModal1">Signup</button>
            <p class="forgot pull-left"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--client signup-->

<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content" id="cont1">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Signup</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Signup/signup_client1">
          <div id="s1" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="sign-text" id="text1" required="true" placeholder="First Name"></input>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="sign-text" id="text2" required="true" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="sign-text" id="text2" required="true" placeholder="Email"></input>
            <input type="text" name="password" class="sign-text" id="text2" required="true" placeholder="Password"></input>
            <input type="text" name="password1" class="sign-text" id="text2" required="true" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"></input>
            <div>
              <input type="submit" id="finish" value="Signup"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="my-signin2">
          <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" data-width="120"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--vendor signup-->
<div id="ven_myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="ven_cont1">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Signup</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="ven_outerbox1">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Signup/signup_vendor">
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="ven_box4" required="true" placeholder="First Name"></input>
          </br>
          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="ven_box5" required="true" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
          </br>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="ven_box6" required="true" placeholder="Email"></input>
          </br>
          <input type="text" name="password" id="ven_box7" minlength="6" required="true" placeholder="Password"></input>
          <!-- <input type="text" name="pass2" id="ven_box7" required="true" placeholder="Re-enter Password"></input> -->
          <button type="submit" name="ven_reg1_button" id="ven_reg1_button">Signup</button>
          <button name="ven_login1_button" id="ven_login1_button">login</button>
        </form>
        <div id="my-signin2">
          <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" data-width="120"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my view file i need a best way to output the validation errors and incorrect id/password errors whenever i try to use flashdata it redirects to homepage but the form doesnt pops up so i need a perfect way.I dont have much knowledge in javascript but i used alert method for showing errors but somewhere it stuck and page became unresponsive i used alert method in my controller file

Comment: plz ignore <?php echo $error; ?> in vendor signin part

Comment: Can you pick a part of your code that best describe the problem, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: there are four forms in the code.You can take one.I have tried showing error using flashdata .Using alert method of js.None worked swiftly

Comment: Please do reading before asking, [ask]

Comment: what do you mean??i am new to web development world i need help